# Checked if object is 'null', but still get type error that object is still possibly 'null'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

so I have an param that expects the type `Record<string, FilterValue | null>`.  This is a built-in type from Ant Design.  TypeScript is giving me the error "Object is possibly 'null'", which makes sense because the Record definition should expect null in some cases.

```js
export type TableOnChangeProps = {
  onChange: (
    pagination: TablePaginationConfig,
    filters: Record<string, FilterValue | null>,
    sorter?: SorterResult<T>,
  ) => void;
};

type FilterValue = (Key | boolean)[];

export default function Item() {
const handleChange: TableOnChangeProps['onChange'] = (pagination, filters) => {
    let temp: Record<string, FilterValue | null> = { ...filterParam };
    Object.keys(filters).forEach((key) => {
      if (filters[key]) {
        temp = { ...temp, [key]: filters[key] };
      } else {
        const { [key]: deletedKey, ...rest } = temp;
        temp = rest;
      }
      if (['downgradable', 'released'].includes(key) && filters[key] && filters[key] !== null && filters[key].length > 1) {
        const { [key]: deletedKey, ...rest } = temp;
        temp = rest;
      }
    });
    setFilter(temp);
  };
}
```

So in the logic above, I made sure to check if `filters[key] !== null` so the type error would go away, but it doesn't.  I'm a little stuck here because I also tried checking if `filters[key]` is an Array, but that didn't help either.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning `filters[key]` to a variable and then checking against it.

So this line:

```
if (['downgradable', 'released'].includes(key) && filters[key] && filters[key] !== null && filters[key].length > 1) {
```

should be:

```
const selectedFilter = filters[key];
if (['downgradable', 'released'].includes(key) && selectedFilter && selectedFilter !== null && selectedFilter.length > 1) {
```

Comment: This worked! Weird this works and my previous implementation didn't, even though it's pretty similar.  Anyways, thanks for the help!